# Two table set a column to no product after lookup

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, set

I have two tables with multiple columns. One of the coulmns is Product. if product is not on table1 then make product='noproduct'. Can someone please help me with this query. Table1 columns name,address,product
table2 column product
If Product not in table2 then product='no product'

Comment: please post some sample data and desired resultset.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to delete the non-existing products instead of corrupting their names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
update table1 set product  = ISNULL(table2.product , 'no product') from
table1 left join table2 on table1.product  = table2.product
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are talking about a left join. you can use the coalesce expression to return custom text if the answer is null.

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx